# What are the reference infos when using Eclipse Batch Compiler

Tags: java, eclipse, ecj

When reading through the [Eclipse Batch Compiler Documentation](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftask-using_batch_compiler.htm) for Java, I came accross the flag `-referenceInfo` whichs description is as follows:

> Compute reference info. This is useful only if connected to the
>   builder. The reference infos are useless otherwise.

What are does reference infos? Are those infos about object references? Is there any documentation available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These ***reference infos*** are **used when** the Eclipse Java Compiler is used **as part of the Eclipse Java IDE** (as so-called *project builder*).

Therefore, there will probably be no documentation for this. But in the code you can see which data is gathered with *-referenceInfo* during compilation (see [`org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.CompilationUnitScope`](https://git.eclipse.org/c/jdt/eclipse.jdt.core.git/tree/org.eclipse.jdt.core/compiler/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/lookup/CompilationUnitScope.java?id=f8480ac357ea4ce5d95c6e2a05c65fefd02632cd#n84)):

```
if (compilerOptions.produceReferenceInfo) {
    this.qualifiedReferences = new SortedCompoundNameVector();
    this.simpleNameReferences = new SortedSimpleNameVector();
    this.rootReferences = new SortedSimpleNameVector();
    this.referencedTypes = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    this.referencedSuperTypesSet = new HashSet<>();
    this.referencedSuperTypes = new ObjectVector();
} else {
    this.qualifiedReferences = null; // used to test if dependencies should be recorded
    this.simpleNameReferences = null;
    this.rootReferences = null;
    this.referencedTypes = null;
    this.referencedSuperTypesSet = null;
    this.referencedSuperTypes = null;
}
```

I guess (but I'm not sure if it's true) that for instance the referenced super types are collected e.g. to be able to quickly display a type hierarchy in the Java IDE.

Comment: Nice, I did not think about looking at the compiler code.